# When is a multiset sorted? Insertion, iteration, both?

Tags: c++, data-structures, language-lawyer, std

I have a multi-set containing pointers to custom types. I have provided a custom sorter to the multi-set that compares on a particular attribute of the custom type.

If I change the value of the attribute on any given item (in a way that would influence the sorting order). Do I have to remove the item from the set and re-insert it to guarantee ordering? Or anytime I create an iterator (or a foreach loop), I will still get the items in order?

I can make a quick test for myself, but I wanted to know if the behavior would be consistent on any platform and compiler or if it is standard.

Edit: Here is an example I tried. I noticed two things.
In a multi-set if I change the value that is used to compare before removing the key, I can no longer remove it. Otherwise, my original thought of removing and reinserting seems the best way for this to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <set>

struct NodePointerCompare;

struct Node {
    int priority;
};

struct NodePointerCompare {
  bool operator()(const Node* lhs, const Node* rhs) const {
        return lhs->priority < rhs->priority;
  }
};



int main()
{
    Node n1{1};
    Node n2{2};
    Node n3{3};
    
    std::multiset<Node*, NodePointerCompare> nodes;
    nodes.insert(&n1);
    nodes.insert(&n2);
    nodes.insert(&n3);
    
    printf("First round\n");
    
    for(Node* n : nodes) {
      printf("%d\n", n->priority);
    }
    
    n1.priority = 10;

    printf("Second round\n");

    for(Node* n : nodes) {
      printf("%d\n", n->priority);
    }

    n1.priority = 1;

    printf("Third round\n");
    nodes.erase(&n1);
    n1.priority = 10;
    nodes.insert(&n1);

    for(Node* n : nodes) {
      printf("%d\n", n->priority);
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I get

```
First round
1
2
3
Second round
10
2
3
Third round
2
3
10
```

Comment: I suspect sorted on insertion and constant access on iteration. I can't find anything that says that it is required this way, but it does say that the insertion must be `O(log(n))` which is a strong recommendation that it sorts here. I would also be surprised if a legacy bidirectional iterator did not have near constant time access.

Comment: Just did and I added an example of what I see

Comment: Depending on exactly what you are trying to do, a `std::priority_queue` might be what you want.  It is good if you want to find the highest priority element, remove it from the queue and put it back with a different priority.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://eel.is/c++draft/associative.reqmts#general-3

> For any two keys k1 and k2 in the same container, calling comp(k1, k2) shall always return the same value.

It is simply illegal to change the change the object in a way that affects how it compares to other objects within the associative container.

If you want to do that, you have to get the object out of the container, apply the change to it, and put it back in. Have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/extract if that's what you want to do.

Comment: I was using a multi-set because I have items with equivalent values on the "priority" attribute. I think... maybe after all, it is better to just use a vector and sort every time I insert then?  or what would be a good structure for something like that. 
A priority queue would not do since I need to access all of the elements in order without removing them

Comment: @cloudraven It really depends on your use-case. If the ordering of values only change once in a while, pulling the value out of the container before changing the value and putting it back in afterwards is the way to go, and the standard library does have few  mechanisms to facilitate that. However, if the frequency of updates is much higher than the frequency of lookups, there comes a point where keeping the collection sorted is just not worth it.

Comment: Lookups where order is important are much more frequent. What are those mechanisms of the standard library?

Comment: @cloudraven https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/extract

Answer (score 2):

> When is a multiset sorted? Insertion, iteration, both?

The standard doesn't specify explicitly, but practically speaking the ordering must be established on insertion.

> If I change the value of the attribute on any given item (in a way that would influence the sorting order). Do I have to remove the item from the set and re-insert it to guarantee ordering?

You may not change the ordering of an element while it is in the set.

However, instead of erase + insert element with different walue, you can extract + modify + re-insert which should be slightly more efficient (or significantly, depending on the element type).

> Here is an example I tried.

The behaviour of the example is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The container must remain sorted at all times because `begin` has constant complexity.  Changing the comparison order of elements in the container is **undefined behavior** per [associative.reqmts.general]/3 (and [res.on.functions]/2.3):

> For any two keys `k1` and `k2` in the same container, calling `comp(k1, k2)` shall always return the same value.

You can use node handles to efficiently modify elements by temporarily removing them from the container, although for elements that are just pointers the only efficiency is avoiding a memory (de)allocation.

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't mean much if the elements are pointers. If I extract and modify the value pointed, wouldnt reinserting force a re-sort?

Comment: @cloudraven: Extracting and reinserting a node handle or removing and reinserting an element equally involves resorting (at just the cost of *O(log n)*); the former can preserve (most of) the value of a complex object, which doesn’t apply to a scalar (*e.g.*, a pointer), although it does also save a memory (de)allocation.